# alternated default sort in GRAILS

Tags: grails, groovy

why the following Groovy snippet returns alternating

[Account: 2222 and 2222, Account: 1111 and 1111] or

[Account: 1111 and 1111, Account: 2222 and 2222]

if you run it multiple times within the Groovy Console ?
I thought the sort statement leads to an ALWAYS descending sort order of the list ???

```
class Account {
    long number
    String code
    String toString() {return "Account: $number and $code"}
    static mapping = {
        sort number:"desc"
    }
}
List items = []
items << new Account(number:1111,code:'1111')
items << new Account(number:2222,code:'2222')
println items.sort()
```

Thanks in advance
Dominik

Answer (score 1):

You don't define an ordering among your *Account* instances. The *mapping* directive is only applicable to GORM mapped classes (IOW: "domain objects"), and will only be used when loading instances of your class from the database AFAIK.

However, you are appending the objects to a plain *List*, which does not know about GORM properties. In order to sort lists of *Account* instances reliably in such a context, you will have to specify an explicit ordering, for example:

```
class Account implements Comparable {

   ...
   def int compareTo(rhs) {
       long onum = rhs.number;
       return (onum > number)? -1 : ((onum < number)? 1 : 0);
   }
   ...
}
```

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg10255.html) has more information about the topic. As to why Groovy sorts the list differently on multiple calls to *list.sort*: well, I have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

Grails has two main default ways to sort:

1. Sort when you query:

   ```
   def airports = Airport.list(sort:'name')
   ```
2. Put a default sorting method on that object:

   ```
   class Airport {
    …
    static mapping = {
     sort name:"desc"
    }
   }
   ```

The above is taken from the [grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.3%20Default%20Sort%20Order).